# How to delete color attribute option by using label in Magento 2?

Tags: product-attribute, delete, option

Can we delete product attribute options by using label?

For example say attribute:color has options like green, red, yellow how to delete red from this? I used below code.

```
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

        $eavConfig = $objectManager->get('Magento\Eav\Model\Config');

        $attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color);

        $id = $attribute->getAttributeId();

        $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
        foreach ($options as $option) {             
            $options['delete'][$option['value']] = true; 
            $options['value'][$option['value']] = true;
        }

        $eavSetup = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup');
        $eavSetup->addAttributeOption($options);
```

It is deleting all the options. I need to delete specific option.

Comment: It works great. But what if i want to add a new option? Can i use something like $options['create'][$option['value']] = true;
$options['value'][$option['Yellow']] = true;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$eavAttribute = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
$attribute = $eavAttribute->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');

$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();

foreach ($options as $option) {
    if($option['label'] == 'Red'){
        $options['delete'][$option['value']] = true; 
        $options['value'][$option['value']] = true;
    }
}

$setupObject = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup');
$setupObject->addAttributeOption($options);
?>
```

Comment: I have used your code with slight changes, deleting options in bulk by reading the json into array with foreach, i have posted the answer below, that is not working. can you pls check it where i am wrong

Comment: Create a question, I ll check and answer. Also provide the json value in correct format.

Comment: here is my question, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/258787/create-update-attribute-option-custom-api-issue

Answer (score 0):

```
   "OptionValues": [ 
         { 
            "OptionId": "22",  
            "OptionName": "Test" 
         },
         { 
            "OptionId": "21",
            "OptionName" : "Test 2"
         } 

      <?php
     $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

     $eavAttribute = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
     $attribute = $eavAttribute->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');

       $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
       foreach($OptionValues as $optValue){
                    $optionIdVal = $optValue['OptionName'];
                    foreach ($options as $option) {
                        if($option['label'] == $optionIdVal){
                            $options['delete'][$option['value']] = true; 
                            $options['value'][$option['value']] = true;
                        }
                    }
                }


     $setupObject = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup');
     $setupObject->addAttributeOption($options);
  ?>
```