# Create/Update Attribute Option Custom api issue

Tags: product-attribute, rest-api, attribute-options

I have created custom rest api to create/update attribute options by attribute_id.

Here is my webapi.xml file code.

```
 <route url="/V1/attribute/AttributeOption" method="POST">
    <service class="Vendor\Module\Api\AttributeInterface" method="AttributeOption"/>       
</route>
```

Api/AttributeInterface.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Api;

interface AttributeInterface
{
 /**
 * POST for attribute api
 * @param mixed $param
 * @return array
 */

  public function AttributeOption($params);
}
```

Model/Attribute.php

```
  <?php
   namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
   use Vendor\Module\Api\AttributeInterface;
   use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
   use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
   class Attribute implements AttributeInterface
  {
   protected $_eavSetupFactory;
   protected $_storeManager;
   protected $_attributeFactory;
   protected $eavAttributeFactory;
   protected $attributeOptionManagement;
   protected $productFactory;   
   private $productAttributeRepository;
   protected $objectManager;
   public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $attributeFactory,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\AttributeFactory $eavAttributeFactory,
    \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeOptionManagementInterface $attributeOptionManagement,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository $productAttributeRepository
) {
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
    $this->eavAttributeFactory = $eavAttributeFactory;
    $this->attributeOptionManagement = $attributeOptionManagement;
    $this->productFactory = $productFactory;        
    $this->productAttributeRepository = $productAttributeRepository;
  }

  public function AttributeOption($params) {        
      // looking for logic to create / update options from request
  }

}
```

Here is my json Request:

```
 {
"params":{  
    "Type": "create",
    "attribute_id" : "159",
        "OptionValues": [ 
         { 
            "OptionId": "01",  
            "OptionName": "Test" 
         },
         { 
            "OptionId": "Null",
            "OptionName" : "Test2"
         } 
     ] 
   }
}
```

I need to create the option for particular attribute by reading the above json,

if OptionId = null i need to create the new option otherwise

I need to update the label for option_id.

Can anyone help me with this please.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below:

```
$OptionValues = json_decode('{"params":{"Type": "create", "attribute_id" : "159", "OptionValues": [{ "OptionId": "01", "OptionName": "Test"}, { "OptionId": "Null", "OptionName" : "Test2"}]}}');

foreach($OptionValues->params->OptionValues as $optValue){
    $optionVal = $option->OptionName;
    if($option->OptionId == NULL){
        //Create Code
    }
    else{
        //Update Code
    }
}
```

Now update your code according to your requirement.

Comment: hi @sukumar, is it possible to update me the code for attribute option create/update

Comment: hi @Sukumar, can you help me on this issue?https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart